# How can I allow user to Login if their status is 'active'?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating admin dashboard wherein accounts's `status: 'active`' must be active first before logging in.

This is my database, the status `"active"`.

[image]

But when I run it to my backend

```
  router.post('/login', async (req,res) =>{
    try {
        const studentId = await User.findOne({studentId: req.body.studentId})
        if(!studentId) return res.status(404).json("User is not yet accepted")
        
        
        const studentStatus = await User.findOne({status: 'active'})

        if(studentStatus === 'active'){
            const isPasswordCorrect = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
                studentId.password,
                process.env.PASSWORD_SEC
                )
            
            const originalPassowrd = isPasswordCorrect.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
                if(originalPassowrd !== req.body.password) 
                 return res.status(400).json("Incorrect password")
    
                 const acessToken = jwt.sign({
                    id:studentId._id, isAdmin: studentId.isAdmin
                 }, process.env.JWT_KEY, {expiresIn: "3d"})
    
            const {password, ...others} = studentId._doc
            res.status(200).json({...others, acessToken})
        }else{
           return res.status(400).json("Still Pending Account")
        }   
        } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({message:error.message})
    }
})
```

I'm receiving an error of

> "Still Pending Account"

UserSchema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        firstname: {type: String, required: true},
        middlename: {type: String},
        lastname: {type: String, required: true},
        email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        department: {type: String, required: true},
        password: {type:String, required: true},
        studentId: {type:String,required:true,unique:true},
        img: {type: String},
        isAdmin: {type: Boolean,default: false},
        status: {type:String, default: "active"},
    }
, {timestamps: true}
)
```

**EDIT**:

I think I've solved it, I grab the information of `others.status` and check if it's equal to 'active`

```
router.post('/login', async (req,res) =>{
    try {
        const studentId = await User.findOne({studentId: req.body.studentId})
        if(!studentId) return res.status(404).json("User is not yet accepted")
        
        
            const isPasswordCorrect = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
                studentId.password,
                process.env.PASSWORD_SEC
                )
            
            const originalPassowrd = isPasswordCorrect.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
                if(originalPassowrd !== req.body.password) 
                 return res.status(400).json("Incorrect password")
    
                 const acessToken = jwt.sign({
                    id:studentId._id, isAdmin: studentId.isAdmin
                 }, process.env.JWT_KEY, {expiresIn: "3d"})
    
            const {password, ...others} = studentId._doc

            if(others.status === 'active'){
                res.status(200).json({...others, acessToken})
            }
            else{
                res.status(404).json("Account still Pending")
            }        

        } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({message:error.message})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`User.findOne({status: 'active'})` return a whole record of student, not single student status field

You can fix by change if statement to check status field

```
if(studentStatus.status === 'active'){
...
```